# mercurial hg and kdiff3

Tags: mercurial, kdiff3

I am in windows. I use Mercurial hg. I made a clone of a project (hg clone) then hg pull another project (hg pull). So mercurial asks me to do a merge of the two projects. And then there is a conflict between the two projects. And now I know what to do because kdiff3 does not open automatically so that I can resolve the conflict.

So if someone had an idea of ​​how I could make kdiff3 opens automatically when mercurial encounter conflict.

Thank you very much and good day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your ***mercurial.ini*** file as per the instruction in this link:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/KDiff3

and setting the parameter ***cmd.kdiff3*** to the path of kdiff executable file.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, at least on mac. Although THG is horribly broken on mac in many ways so, maybe it's related.